# Visual Studio 2010 Debugging "if (var == NULL)" not triggering

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, null, if-statement

### Solved - Problem with constructor

[Matthew Flaschen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/47773/matthew-flaschen) and [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) pointed out the problem of the overloaded constructor of `Node(int)` calling `Node()` which doesn't work [because...](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238419/blueraja-danny-pflughoeft)
**Thanks guys!**

---

I have built a program (I am debugging it) and have run into a weird problem... A `if` statement is not getting triggered when it should be... This is a school project where we must build an AVL Tree with at least one 'optimizing' feature.

I am sure and have tested that the `rdown` and `ldown` work (as the balancing factors) - the tree is not perfectly balanced. Rather it is based on the hight of the branches (i.e. - `balance()` should only return (1,0,-1) otherwise it is unbalanced.

I hope this is enough information to solve this weird problem... I have never ran into anything like this before with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

### Node struct:

```
struct Node {
    int data;           // the data in the Node
    int rdown;          // the number of ellements below the node on the right side
    int ldown;          // the number of ellements below the node on the left side
    Node * parrent;     // the node's parrent
    Node * lchild;      // the nodes left child
    Node * rchild;      // the nodes right child

    Node () { rdown = 0, ldown = 0; data = 0; parrent = NULL; lchild = NULL; rchild = NULL; }
    Node (int dat) {rdown = 0, ldown = 0; parrent = NULL; lchild = NULL; rchild = NULL; data = dat; } 
    bool end() { if (lchild == NULL && rchild == NULL) return true;     // check if this node is the 'end of the line' - where it doesn't
                 return false; }                                        // have any children
    bool goodToAdd() { if (lchild == NULL || rchild == NULL) return true;   // make sture the current node has at least one spot to add
                       return false; }                                      // a new node to - either lchild or rchild must be NULL

    int balance() { return (ldown - rdown); }                           // get a balance number for the node
};
```

### Search function that is causing the problems

```
Node * AVL_Tree::search(const Node * num) {
 Node * tmpNode = AVL_Tree::root;      // tmpNode is a place holder for the search
 for (int i = 1; true; i++) {     // increment int i to check for excess searching -> pervents endless loop
  if (tmpNode == NULL) //****** causing problems********  // the search has reached a dead end (the data is not contained) ==>  NULL
   return NULL;
  if (tmpNode->data == num->data)   // if the data of num is the same as tmpNode the data is contained ==>  Node *
   return tmpNode;
            // since the node has not been found yet move down the tree...
  if (tmpNode->data > num->data && tmpNode->lchild != NULL) // if the data is smaller than the tmpNode move to the lchild
   tmpNode = tmpNode->lchild;
  else if (tmpNode->rchild != NULL)    // since the node has been proven to not be = to the data to be searched for
   tmpNode = tmpNode->rchild;    // and it is not smaller... move to the right

  if (i > (root->ldown + 1) && i > (root->rdown + 1) ) {  // the while loop has searched suffecent time and has not ended
   string tmp = "the search incountered a critical error... aborting..."; // to prevent an endless loop the string error
   throw tmp;            // is thrown (should not happen) - indicates a broken tree
  }
 }
}
```

---

### A screen shot of the first encounter with the `for loop`

[image]

### A screen shot of the second encounter with the `for loop`

If you would note in the 'Autos' tab at the bottom that all the data and the node itself's address is `NULL` - yet in the next screen shot it continues
[image]

### The program continues!!! what?>!

I pushed F-10 (the 'go to next command' button) ... and it jumps right over the statement? why?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0xcdcdcdcd` is not a NULL pointer - that value is used in the debug builds of MSVC for memory that has been allocated but not initialized.

See [When and why will an OS initialise memory to 0xCD, 0xDD, etc. on malloc/free/new/delete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370195/when-and-why-will-an-os-initialise-memory-to-0xcd-0xdd-etc-on-malloc-free-new/370362#370362) for more details.

The root of your problem might be in the constructor that takes an `int` parameter:

```
Node (int dat) { Node(); data = dat; }
```

The `Node();` statement ends up doing nothing.  This constructor leaves most of the members of the structure uninitialized.

Comment: So the question is How do I catch this problem? - why would the compiler not contain a `#if _DEBUG` statement in the `if` code. This seems like an easy error to avoid?

Comment: @Wallter: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.3  @Michael: Good catch, I glazed right over that

Answer (score 2):

`tmpNode` is not null in any screenshot.

It's first `0x00294820`, then `0xcdcdcdcd`.  The second is the [magic](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-p/win32/tutorials/article.php/c9535) debug value for uninitialized `malloc`ed memory.

Comment: the screen shots were from two different runs - I wanted to add the illustrations... If you notice in the first screenshot the lchild is `NULL` there is no place in the runtime that could change it to a 'non-NULL' value

Comment: First, it would probably be clearer to focus on one run at a time.  Second, `lchild` not `NULL` in any screenshot either.  It's 0xcdcdcdcd in the first.

Answer (score 1):

`NULL`, in C++, tends to be (but is not guaranteed to be) `0`.

In your second/third screenshots, `tmpNode = 0xcdcdcdcd`, which is not `NULL`.  `0xcdcdcdcd` is the value Visual Studio gives to uninitialized variables (when running a debug release).

Make sure to initialize all all your nodes' fields:

```
Node* root = NULL;
or
Node* root = new Node(); //Don't forget to delete!
```

Setting fields to NULL is not done automatically in C++ as it is in other languages like Java and C#.

Comment: To focus down the problem I didn't add the class definition of `AVL_Tree`. root is a member of AVL_Tree -> AVL_Tree:root

Answer (score 0):

`tmpNode` is referencing uninitialized memory, which is generally not guaranteed to be null.  For instance, the following statement does not guarantee that `tmpNode` is null.

```
Node* tmpNode;  // or assignment to another uninitialized variable.
```

You are assigning `tmpNode` to `root` and I suspect that `root` is uninitialized, hence the non-null value of `tmpNode`.  Please check your initialization of `root` -- I cannot comment on it as you haven't posted this specific code.

Comment: Yes, but `Node()` gets called when it's initiated? in the `Node()` it defines both `lchild` and `rchild` as `NULL` - the call is: `Node * tmpNode = new Node(num);`

Comment: I didn't want to include all the code but: root = `AVL_Tree::root` it's part of the class and is initiated